# Combinatorics: Can anyone give a hint?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm practicing combinatorics then I got stuck in this problem.

Suppose that I have an unlimited supply of identical math books, history books and physics books. All are the same size, and I have room on a shelf for 8 books. In how many ways can I arrange 8 books on the shelf if no two books of the same type can be adjacent?

Comment: Let's take it one step at a time. You have $8$ spaces to fill. Let's start with the leftmost space. In how many different ways can you fill that space? Next, after that space has been filled, how many choices do you have for filling the second space from the left?

Comment: Well I would have 3 for the left most space it could be Math, Physics or History, the next space would have two, since I can't have the same book beside one another, am I doing it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider eight spaces, each of which needs to be filled by a book. As all the books of their respective subjects is identical, you basically have 3 choices to fill a space (without considering your other condition).

**Starting from the left most space:**

For the first space, you have 3 choices: Either maths, history or physics.

For the second space, you cannot have the book that was placed in the first space. Thus, you will have 2 choices.

For the third space, you will still have 2 choices - as only the subject placed in the second space can't be placed there.

Continuing, each space after the first can be filled by either of 2 subjects. So that means that the answer will be:

> $$3*2*2*2*2*2*2*2 = 3*2^7$$

Comment: To be honest, I felt a little bit stupid not to realize this simple solution. haha! Thanks, now I gotta go back and solve more problems. :D

Comment: @JCK Happens xD Especially in this topic. I have fared much worse...